# Cannot use protontricks, winetricks, because wine is looking for libraries in wrong location

Tags: wine, steam, winetricks

Wine seems to be looking for libraries / shared objects in the wrong location. Running `winetricks` or `protontricks` to establish compatability for a game gets me to the following error.

```
wine: failed to initialize: /home/vagrant/build-proton_5.13-local/dist-wine32/lib/wine/ntdll.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Game is considered exited.
```

Another example

```
/home/ubuntu/.cache/protontricks/proton/proton_5.13-local/bin/wine cmd.exe /c echo '%ProgramFiles%' returned empty string, error message "wine: failed to initialize: /home/vagrant/build-proton_5.13-local/dist-wine32/lib/wine/ntdll.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"
```

I've tried a number of troubleshooting suggestions but it's all felt like fitting square pegs into circle shaped holes. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Proton, building it from source, fiddling with Wine versions, reinstalling winetricks and protontricks, etc. Nothing budges this error. I'm presuming that there are environmental variables that aren't being set, but I'm not sure what they are or ought to be. This is my suspicion because I am aware that Proton is built using `vagrant`, and those seem to be the default directories it's looking for here.

Comment: @guiverc Ubuntu 18.04, installed from Steam. It’s Elite Dangerous.

Comment: protontricks or any of the wine overrides do not work with Proton 5.13-1 currently (I am not sure why exactly, though). Try using Proton 5.0-9. But beware, you may have to delete the 5.13-1 prefix entirely, because a fallback does not work eiither.

Comment: Do you mean forcing Proton to an earlier version, deleting the pix for the application, running the game at least once, and then trying protontricks? I did try that, it gives the same error.

Comment: I diagnosed it a bit more. This is only occurring when I go in and run Proton 5.13's Wine exe manually.

Comment: @BradleyEvans Were you able to solve this? I am currently facing the exact same issue.

Comment: Honestly, I gave up on it and just started using the Windows applications causing this issue from within a VM. @AartStuurman

Answer (score 1):

According to this issue https://github.com/Matoking/protontricks/issues/72 the new steam runtime `soldier` will be supported in future releases of protontricks.

If it does not run, it is still possible to run protontricks with an older Proton version, e.g.:

```sh
PROTON_VERSION='Proton 5.0' protontricks --gui
```

Comment: works well but make sure you have the correct version